# AngularJS Controller not getting executed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angularjs in asp.net core website which has jquery as well. AngularJS is being used for a small part of the website. Below is the AngularJS HTML

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('dashBoardApp', []);
    console.log(app);
    var xx = app.controller('dashBoardController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'Test';
        
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<div ng-app="dashBoardApp">
        <div ng-controller="dashBoardController">
            <p>{{5+5}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I must be doing something stupid. But unable to figure out.

Comment: I'm thinking this is just an issue with how AngularJS is being referenced / pulled in. Can you provide how you are pulling AngularJS into your view? 

Also: plugging your exact code directly into a Plunkr sample renders "5 + 5" correctly. The plunk was made using the AngularJS 1.6.X template.

https://embed.plnkr.co/9nlEOYiUIsBodKd5FK3o/

Comment: I am pulling my hair to resolve this. I can see the app object getting created properly in the app. I am wondering is it anything to do Jquery and AngularJS.

Comment: Ya take a look at @MarcusHöglund 's answer below -- make sure that you reference AngularJS AFTER JQuery.

Comment: @user2580925 didn't my answer solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it did solve my problem. Initially, jquery was getting loaded twice. this caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the angular lib

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Then it works like a charm

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('dashBoardApp', []);
    console.log(app);
    var xx = app.controller('dashBoardController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'Test';
        
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="dashBoardApp">
    <div ng-controller="dashBoardController">
        <p>{{5+5}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```